# Add date and time in coffee script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have date and time like this for start date

```
  start_year = "2021"
  start_month = "01"
  start_day = "15"
  start_hour = "20"
  start_minute = "55"
  start_second = "25"
```

I need to add this value in start date:

```
interval = $("#interval").val(); // 10
```

This value is coming as 10. Now I want to convert this number in minute and add in start time and store in end time.
So, that end time should be like 2021 01 15 21 05 25

For that I have converted start date like this:

```
 date = Date(Date.parse(start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, start_minute)).
```

Date is coming in this format. Mon Jan 15 2021 20:55:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). Now I want to add 10 minutes in this time.

Could somene please help me in getting this.

Comment: *Hint:* Use a new [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and `setMinutes()` then parse that into required format

Comment: date = Date(Date.parse(start_year, start_month, start_day, start_hour, start_minute)).
Date is coming in this format. Mon Jan 15 2021 20:55:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: OK so include that attempt in question along with where you are stuck using it. There are lots of date formatting resources found in a simple search